# C#. Change one character color in a sentence

Tags: c#, fonts

How can I change the color of characters? I want A and B and C to become blue.

```
Console.Write("Choose between, A or B or C : ");
```

The only way I found online was `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue`, but I only need A B C to be blue, not the whole sentence.

Comment: @stickybit has what looks like the right answer. You may want to generalize your solution by encoding the format (colors) along with your data (the letters) in some fashion and then writing code that reads that information and spits out the right information to the console (or whatever renderer you are using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the color than write what you want to have in that color and reset the color and write what you want to have in the recent color.

```
ConsoleColor recentForegroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
Console.Write("Choose between, ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Write("A");
Console.ForegroundColor = recentForegroundColor;
Console.Write(" or ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Write("B");
Console.ForegroundColor = recentForegroundColor;
Console.Write(" or ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Write("C");
Console.ForegroundColor = recentForegroundColor;
Console.Write(" : ");
```